# LaTeX command outputs first result every time its called

Tags: latex

I have a command defined as:

```
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\tikzset{fading text/.style={}}

\newcommand\fadingtext[2][]{%
  \begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name = fading letter]
    \node[text = transparent!0, inner xsep = 0pt, outer xsep = 0pt] {#2};
  \end{tikzfadingfrompicture}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline = (textnode.base)]
    \node[inner sep = 0pt, outer sep = 0pt] (textnode) {\phantom{#2}};
    \shade[path fading = fading letter, fading text, #1, fit fading = false]
    (textnode.south west) rectangle (textnode.north east);% 
  \end{tikzpicture}% 
}
```

When I use this command like `\fadingtext[left color = awesome-red, right color = text]{Hello}`, the text outputs "Hello". But if I use it again eg `\fadingtext[left color = awesome-red, right color = text]{Wow}`, this still prints "Hello".

Any ideas why it seems to be caching the first argument?

EDIT: Even if I redefine the command (and name it something else), the problem is still there.

`\fadingtext1{Hello}` prints `Hello`

`\fadingtext2{Wow}` prints `Hello`

EDIT2: Getting rid of command all together and simply pasting the inner code multiple times still has the same problem.

EDIT3: Discovered the issue!! (Still need help)

`\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name = fading letter]`

Here because I set a name for this section, it stores this as a variable. This never gets updated after the first time I use this function, so `fading letter` never changes. Any idea around this?